# Remove\Delete a binding object

Tags: java

I have 3 hashTables/List.
Inside them, I have a class that was created once and it pointing by reference to all the places.
now I would like to remove it without going to all the Lists.
is it possible?

I saw here there is an option to get the object from one of the lists then set it to null.
Didn't work for me.
If I'm changing one of the item prop then it's of course change all over.
A small example of what I would like to do:

```
    Day day = new Day();
    meetingDayList.add(day);
    meetingDayList2.add(day);
    meetingDayList3.add(day);

    Day day2 = meetingDayList.stream().filter(day1 -> day1.getDayDate().isEqual(day.getDayDate())).findAny().get();
    day2 = null; // Or somehow remove it from the memory so it will not show anymore
```

get the object from one of the arrays and remove it from the memory so it will remove from all the lists.
I tried to Override finalize and destroy without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the objects you create reference the same object in memory, the only way to get it garbage collected would be not to have any references to it anymore.

So in your case, you would have to remove the object from all of the lists you added it too.

```
Day day = new Day();
addToList(day, list1);
addToList(day, list2);
addToList(day, list3);
```

Even though the object was created only once, it exists in three lists here. you would have to remove it from all x lists.

```
removeFromList(day, list1);
removeFromList(day, list2);
removeFromList(day, list3);
```

In your specific example, it would be:

```
 Day day2 = ... //obtain day2;
 // for all of your lists
 removeFromList(day2, list_x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have already done that. Use collect instead of findAmy()

```
List<MeetingDayList> yourList = meetingDayList.stream().filter(day1 -> day1.getDayDate().isEqual(day.getDayDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You will collect list w/o filter data.